# Tree classifier to graphviz ERROR

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I had made a Tree Classifier named model and tried to use the export graphviz function like this:

```
export_graphviz(decision_tree=model,
                    out_file='NT_model.dot',
                    feature_names=X_train.columns,
                    class_names=model.classes_,
                    leaves_parallel=True,
                    filled=True,
                    rotate=False,
                    rounded=True)
```

For some reason my run had raised this exception:

> ---
>
> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-298-40fe56bb0c85> in <module>()
>       6                     filled=True,
>       7                     rotate=False,
> ----> 8                     rounded=True)
>
> C:\Users\yonatanv\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-
> packages\sklearn\tree\export.py in export_graphviz(decision_tree, out_file, 
> max_depth, feature_names, class_names, label, filled, leaves_parallel, 
> impurity, node_ids, proportion, rotate, rounded, special_characters)
>     431             recurse(decision_tree, 0, criterion="impurity")
>     432         else:
> --> 433             recurse(decision_tree.tree_, 0, 
> criterion=decision_tree.criterion)
>     434
>     435         # If required, draw leaf nodes at same depth as each other
>
> C:\Users\yonatanv\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-
> packages\sklearn\tree\export.py in recurse(tree, node_id, criterion, parent, 
> depth)
>     319             out_file.write('%d [label=%s'
>     320                            % (node_id,
> --> 321                               node_to_str(tree, node_id, 
> criterion)))
>     322
>     323             if filled:
>
> C:\Users\yonatanv\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-
> packages\sklearn\tree\export.py in node_to_str(tree, node_id, criterion)
>     289                                           np.argmax(value),
>     290                                           characters[2])
> --> 291             node_string += class_name
>     292
>     293         # Clean up any trailing newlines
>
> TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types 
> dtype('<U90') dtype('<U90') dtype('<U90')
> ```

My hyper parameters for the visualizations are those:

```
print(model)
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight={1.0: 10, 0.0: 1}, criterion='gini',
        max_depth=7, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=50,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=0, splitter='best')

print(model.classes_)
[ 0. , 1. ]
```

Help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you are using the updated version of scikit-learn. If still facing the issue, then you need to provide more details for us to help. Start with full stack trace of the error. Then provide the code you used to train the `model` along with some sample data.

Comment: I am using the version that is installed on anaconda3

Comment: Added more decription to my question, thaks for notifying me!

Comment: Looks like an error about the class names present in `model.classes_`. Can you print that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see here specified in the [documentation of export_graphviz](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html), the param `class_names` works for strings, not float or int.

> class_names : list of strings, bool or None, optional (default=None)

Try converting the `model.classes_` to list of strings before passing them in export_graphviz.

Try `class_names=['0', '1']` or `class_names=['0.0', '1.0']` in the call to `export_graphviz()`.

For a more general solution, use:

`class_names=[str(x) for x in model.classes_]`

But is there a specific reason that you are passing float values as `y` in `model.fit()`? Because that is mostly not required in classification task. Do you have actual `y` labels as this only or are you converting string labels to numeric before fitting the model?

Comment: The y labels here are originally numeric, as a binary variable